# How to create a query against 2 databases in mysql linked server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2016, linked-server

I have MSSQL2016, are attached to the server with MySQL ODBC driver (MySQL driver for ODBC 5.3).
In the ODBC settings not specify database default.
How do I make the query to any table?

Query like:
 - `select * from  [Mysql]..[DataBase].[Table]`
 
 - `select * from  [Mysql].[DataBase]..[Table]` error: nvalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "%ls" for linked server "%ls". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema.
 - `select * from  [Mysql].[DataBase].[Table]` error: Invalid object name 'Mysql.DataBase.Table'.
dont work.
But if i set default database queries here are:
 - `select * from  [Mysql]...[Table]` 
work.
But I need the first case to query 2 database on 1 server like:
 - `select * from  [Mysql].[DataBase1].[Table]`
 - `select * from  [Mysql].[DataBase2].[Table]`

How can I do it?

Comment: Why not simply use UNION ALL?

Comment: The problem is not UNION, problem is that I can not create a query to different databases on the same server.

Comment: I don't know anything about mysql but perhaps you could share the error message instead of simply "dont work".

Comment: I have added the error in the first post

Comment: I have 1 server, 2 databases and many tables inside. I can do requests only if I specify the database in ODBC. But then I can't do request to the other base. I tried to specify a database name in the query, but the query does not work. MY sql server linked to mssql.

Comment: when You add Linked server ( MySQL in particular ), You set as part of connection database name. So query have to be like select * from  [Mysql]...[Table]. Another possibility is to ask select * from openquery(Mysql,'select * from Table')